# Get text between two different html tags python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if it were possible to get tags between two completely different texts via the beautifulsoup package in python. I have tried this out:

```
g = soup.find_all(["dtposted"])
for tag in g:
    print(tag)

<dtposted>2020<trnamt>10<fitid>202010<name>RESTAURANT</name></fitid></trnamt></dtposted>
```

I want to be able to separately get the text between dtposted, trnamt, fitid and name. When I look for the next sibling, it returns None, and if I look for a specific tag, it doesn't give me the text between the two tags, but the entire string:

```
for tag in g:
    print(tag.find_all("tnramt")

<trnamt>10<fitid>202010<name>RESTAURANT</name></fitid></trnamt></dtposted>
```

If there is a way to get the 2020, 10, 202010, RESTAURANT all separately, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (using XML parsing)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<dtposted>
   2020
   <trnamt>
      10
      <fitid>
         202010
         <name>RESTAURANT</name>
      </fitid>
   </trnamt>
</dtposted>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.text.strip())
print(root.find('.//trnamt').text.strip())
print(root.find('.//fitid').text.strip())
print(root.find('.//name').text.strip())
```

output

```
2020
10
202010
RESTAURANT
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list to work with:

```
import re

variable = "<trnamt>10<fitid>202010<name>RESTAURANT</name></fitid></trnamt></dtposted>"
text = []
def tostring(html):
    removedhtml = re.compile('<.*?>')
    items = re.sub(removedhtml, ',', html)
    items = items.split(",")
    for item in items: 
        if item.strip(): 
            text.append(item)
    return text

print ((tostring(variable)))
```

output

```
['10', '202010', 'RESTAURANT']
```